# How to display FragmentBreadCrumbs in a Honeycomb app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'd like to use breadcrumbs, but do not find any information how to use it. Is there a running example that uses breadcrumb titles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google IO app has a good example of implementing breadcrumbs with fragments.  You can get the source code from http://code.google.com/p/iosched/.

Specifically, check out `com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.tablet.MapMultiPaneActivity` in the project source.

I've used in one of my apps following the framework of this application and it works well.

Comment: Great! Now I would like to use this in the action bar, any hints?

Comment: It is called MapMultiPaneActivity. Maybe a recent change!?